# LINQ Query for particular situation 2

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Lets say that I have following tables:

```
 Student(id(pk), name)
 Class(id(pk), name)
 StudentClass(id(pk), studentId(fk), classId(fk))
```

Imagine as follows:

`Student` table contains:

```
 (1,"John"), (2, "Mike"), (3,"Josh")
```

`Class` table contains:

```
(1,"Geography"), (2, "Math"), (3, "History"), (4,"Biology)"
```

`StudentClass` table contains:

```
(`1, 1, 1),(2,2,2),(3,3,2)
```

Lets now assume that I have a `StudentClassDTO` class which contains

```
List<string> StudentNames
string ClassName
```

How can I by using using LINQ query get data into `StudentClassDTO`? Any help appreciated.

So the final data will be

1. {John, Geography}
2. {[Mike,Josh] Math}
3. {NULL, History}
4. {Null, Biology}

I tried left outer joins but I could not find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the linq version as left joins using groupjoin:

```
from c in classes
join ljsc in studentClasses 
     on c.id equals ljsc.classId 
     into leftjoinStudentClasses
from sc in leftjoinStudentClasses.DefaultIfEmpty(new StudentClass())
join ljs in students 
     on sc.studentId equals ljs.id 
     into leftjoinStudents
from s in leftjoinStudents.DefaultIfEmpty(new Student())
group new { s,c } by c.name into grp
select new 
{
    @class = grp.Key, students = from ss in grp select ss?.s?.name
}
```

[Link to dotnetfiddle version](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b6C9dP).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Class.Select(c => new ClassStudentDto 
{ 
  ClassName = c.Name, 
  StudentNames = new List<string>(Student.Where(s => StudentClass.Where(cs => cs.ClassId == c.Id).Select(cs => cs.StudentId).Contains(s.Id)).Select(s => s.Name)) 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you use `new List<string>` in one place and `ToList` in another?

Answer (score 0):

If you must have `null`, you can use:

```
var data = from c in context.GetClass
           join sc in context.GetStudentClasses on c.Id equals sc.ClassId into scj
           select new StudentClassDTO {
               ClassName = c.Name,
               StudentNames = scj.Any() ? (from sc in scj
                                           join s in context.GetStudents on sc.StudentId equals s.Id
                                           select s.Name).ToList()
                                        : null
           };
```

But you can eliminate the test if you are okay with an empty list:

```
var data = from c in context.GetClass
           join sc in context.GetStudentClasses on c.Id equals sc.ClassId into scj
           select new StudentClassDTO {
               ClassName = c.Name,
               StudentNames = (from sc in scj
                               join s in context.GetStudents on sc.StudentId equals s.Id
                               select s.Name).ToList()
           };
```